# Modify accessibility settings on macOS with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, settings, accessibility, text-to-speech

I'm writing a macOS app in swift and want to be able to enable text to speech for a user on their computer programmatically once they download my app. I'm not sure what commands to use to reconfigure a user's settings and ask for permission to change their accessibility settings. Does anyone know how to do this or where to find documentation that explains how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Apple requires that you ask explicity for the accessibillity settings. From sierra it is not possible to set this over the Database anymore. So the User has to click and enable your app for accessibility.

```
public func checkAccess() -> Bool{
    //get the value for accesibility
    let checkOptPrompt = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as NSString
    //set the options: false means it wont ask
    //true means it will popup and ask
    let options = [checkOptPrompt: true]
    //translate into boolean value
    let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options as CFDictionary?)
    return accessEnabled
}
```